# Configure Homescreen Layout with Configuration-Profile under iOS 10

Tags: ios, mdm, configuration-profile

We are configuring supervised iOS devices via a Mobile Device Management solution.
 We set the homescreen layout via a configuration profile with the payload type com.apple.homescreenlayout.
 We used this as a template :
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7505009?start=0&tstart=0

Under iOS 9, everything worked as expected. With iOS 10, we can not install the profile anymore.
Installation fails with Apple Configurator :
"The profile “XYZ” could not be installed because it is invalid"

 Does anybody have a working example of a homescreen layout configuration profile?